# where SCM Skip configuration in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

In my blue orcean Jenkins I installed [SCM Skip](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scmskip/) and I using multibranch.

Where I can find the configuration to edit the `pattern`. I need it to run in global mode. meaning its not per stage/step.

[image]

Comment: Check the plugin configuration under the Build Environment section of a free style job

Comment: I don't have freestyle job. multibranch that what blue ocean creates for me

Comment: Can you see `Build Environment` in `Build Configuration`? Did you check if the plugin is installed properly in Plugin section?

Comment: The plugin is installed. Under `Build Configuration` I have only `Jenkinsfile`. yet, I don't see the configuration